# CPP program displays shadows the perimeter error

Tags: c++

I have not seen this error before and have searched to find the answer but can't.  I'm not sure what the problem is but the compiler is pointing to the double roomCharge for some reason. The compiler error is: [Error] declaration of 'double roomCharge' shadows a parameter.

```
void calcRoomCharge(double roomCharge, double TotalBill)
{
    double numNights = 0.0;
    double nightRate = 0.0;
    double roomSvcCharge = 0.0;
    double telephoneCharge = 0.0;
    double roomCharge = 0.0;
    double totalBill = 0.0;
    cout << "Enter the number of nights\n" << endl;
    cin >> numNights;
    cout << "Enter the nightRate\n" << endl;
    cin >> nightRate;
    cout << "Enter the roomSvcCharge\n" << endl;
    cin >> roomSvcCharge;
    cout << "Enter the telephoneCharge\n" <<endl;
    cin >> telephoneCharge;
    roomCharge = numNights * nightRate;
    totalBill = roomCharge + roomSvcCharge + telephoneCharge;
    cout << "The room charge is: $" << "%d/n" << endl;
    cout << "The Total of the bill is: $ " << "%d/n" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please cite the error message. You should also try to minimize the example to get the shortest version, where the error still appears.

Comment: You have a parameter named `roomCharge` and you declare another local variable with the same name `double roomCharge = 0.0;` which hides the parameter.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks I didn't notice that at the time.  I removed the doubles between the brackets and the program compiled cleanly.  Thanks for your input.